# java interpreter and compiler rule violation

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I have a "theoretic" question but this is in order to understand something behind the `java` compilation rules (or interpreter maybe).

Suppose we have the following code:

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

class X {
    public B getValue(){return null;}
}

class Y extends X {
    public A getValue(){return null;} //compilation error here
}

class Z {
    public List<A> getAList(List<B> x) {return x;} //compilation error here
}
```

**Note**: I know what are the syntax errors and how to fix them.

My questions are:

1. What could have happen in runtime if we would "ignore" (**in theory**) the compiler errors? What does this syntax error meant to avoid?
2. Why the violation of the rule would cause a runtime error?

Comment: Undefined behaviour, I suppose. All sorts of things wouldn't work correctly anymore (polymorphism, virtual method dispatch, etc) which is why a set of rules is determined to which your code should adhere to (the JLS). Nobody bothers to find out the exact problems caused by "ignoring" these compilation errors simply because it's entirely theoretical. Thus: undefined.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - "Undefined behavior" is not the answer i was looking for. I edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: It may not be what you're looking for but I doubt you'll get anything else. The behaviour you're asking about is literally not defined so you can only guess about this hypothetical scenario. Maybe the wrong methods are executed? Maybe the runtime starts throwing errors? Who knows.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - i believe it is related to memory stuff, interpretation, java syntax/method evaluation, OS registers and etc. There is a proper explanation for it. I just couldn't find it (yet)

Comment: @ZivLevy I have a few questions for you. Do you know dynamic method dispatch is? Do you know what return type co-variance is? Do you think these features will be possible without putting the compilation restrictions that you fantasize about removing? If the answer to my last question to you is a no, then you have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
What could have happen in runtime if we would "ignore" (in theory) the compiler errors?
```

The compiler transforms Java code into Byte code, which is just set of instructions. To do this, it does need very concrete rules to know what to do - like key words, brackets - the syntax.

If the syntax is wrong, it does not know what to do with it, therefore it cannot transform it.

For compiler there is not big difference between trying to make program of random char sequence like this : `oawpgapwo nap gunapoigu awpougn awpougn apowrgn pagn pawog poawng panbx` and something you consider "almost program, but with few syntax error".

Answer (score 0):

```
class Y extends X {

        @Override //class Y extends class X which has a public method B getValue()
        public B getValue() {
            return super.getValue();  
        }

        private A getValue() {return null}
```

X has a method named getValue() 
Y extends X so Y has the same method getValue() from his super class.
So how the compiler will know which one of your getValue() methods you want to use if they both has the same name?

You can answer your second question alone if you understand the answer of the first ;)